# Laravel Pagination リンクは上手く接続していません。

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

ViewページではPaginationを表示していますが、番号が横並になっていないし、リンクを押したらNextページに行くのではなくて、メインページに戻ってしまいます。原因について意見はある方いますか？

これはリンクの見た目：
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Controller は：

```
$q = $request->q;
        if ($q !== null && trim($q) !== ""){//here

            $estates = \DB::table('allestates')
                ->where("building_name","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orWhere("address","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orWhere("company_name","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orWhere("region","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orderBy('price')->get();


            $showPerPage = 10;

            $perPagedData = $estates
                ->slice((request()->get('page')) * $showPerPage, $showPerPage)
                ->all();

            $estates = new \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator($perPagedData, count($estates), $showPerPage, request()
                ->get('page'));


            if(count($estates) > 0){
                return view("search", compact('estates'))->withQuery($q);
            }

        }

        $estates = array();//here
        return view("search", compact('estates'))->withMessage("No Found!");//here
    }
```

ありがとうございます。

view.bladeではこれで呼んでいます。`{{ $estates->links() }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

問題が解決しました。

Controllerをこれに変えて

```
$q = $request->q;
$estates = \DB::table('allestates')
                ->where("building_name","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orWhere("address","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orWhere("company_name","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orWhere("region","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orderBy('price')->paginate(10);

return view("search", compact('estates','q'));
```

View.bladeをこれに変えて

```
@if(count($estates))
    @foreach($estates as $estate)
        <!-- ... -->
    @endforeach
    {{ $estates ->appends(['q' => $q])->links() }}
@else
    <div class="alert">
        Not found!
    </div>
@endif
```

それでRouteをこのようにしました、

```
Route::get("/search", "PagesController@search")->name('search.route');
```